# macのローカル環境にpsycopg2のインストールができない

Tags: macos, django, postgresql

プログラミング、環境構築の初心者です。

Mac, python3, django, postgresqlを利用して、ローカルの環境でWEBアプリを開発しています。

ローカルホストで、開発しているdjangoのプログラムをサーバーで起動すると、psycoog2がないとエラーが出るので、macのローカル環境にpsycopg2のインストールを試しているのですが、エラーが消えずこの先に進めない状況です。

関係しそうなエラーのキーワードで、色々ググっているのですが、解決できない状況で困っています。
解決の方法について、ご教授いただきないでしょうか？

これまでに行った事は、
①　brewのインストール
②　$ brew install postgresql　でpostgresqlのインストール

関係するバージョンは、
Mac: mojave 10.14.6
Python: 3.7.5
Django: 3.0.0
Postgresql:12.1

以下にエラーの内容を載せます

・Djangoのプログラムをローカルでサーバー起動時のエラー

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named ‘psycopg2'
```

・sudo pip3 install psycopg2 実行時エラー

```
WARNING: The directory '/Users/apple/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
WARNING: The directory '/Users/apple/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting psycopg2
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/d7/6a93c99b5ba4d4d22daa3928b983cec66df4536ca50b22ce5dcac65e4e71/psycopg2-2.8.4.tar.gz (377kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 378kB 706kB/s 
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-o7hidoik/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-o7hidoik/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-yxgv9_lq/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: /private/tmp/pip-install-o7hidoik/psycopg2/
    Complete output (144 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_lru_cache.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    running build_ext
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/green.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/green.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/pqpath.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/pqpath.o
    psycopg/pqpath.c:135:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                    PQstatus(conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(*pgres)));
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    psycopg/pqpath.c:1714:11: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
        ret = 1;
              ^
    psycopg/pqpath.c:1819:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                    PQstatus(curs->conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(curs->pgres)));
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    3 warnings generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/utils.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/utils.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/bytes_format.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o
    In file included from psycopg/bytes_format.c:81:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^

〜中略〜

    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/typecast.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/typecast.o
    gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/green.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/pqpath.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/utils.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/libpq_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/win32_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/solaris_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/connection_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/cursor_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/column_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_message_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/error_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/conninfo_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/lobject_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/lobject_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/notify_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/xid_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/typecast.o -L/usr/local/lib -lpq -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so
    ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-o7hidoik/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-o7hidoik/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-yxgv9_lq/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

### 追記

```sh
$ openssl version
LibreSSL 2.6.5
$ type openssl
openssl is hashed (/usr/bin/openssl)
```

### 追記

xcode-select --installを行いましたが、インストール済みでした

```
(venv) ApplenoMBP:harvest_timer apple$ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

### 追記

「pip --no-cache install psycopg2 のように -no-cache オプションを使うとキャッシュを無視できるので試してみてください。」
を行った後のエラーの内容は以下のとおりです。

```
(venv) ApplenoMBP:harvest_timer apple$ sudo pip3 --no-cache install psycopg2
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
Collecting psycopg2
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/d7/6a93c99b5ba4d4d22daa3928b983cec66df4536ca50b22ce5dcac65e4e71/psycopg2-2.8.4.tar.gz (377kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 378kB 2.9MB/s 
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
    Complete output from command /Users/apple/GoogleDrive/harvest_timer/harvest_timer/venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-install-plxviv83/psycopg2/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-xd6k1r8g/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/apple/GoogleDrive/harvest_timer/harvest_timer/venv/include/site/python3.7/psycopg2:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_lru_cache.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    running build_ext
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/harvest_timer/harvest_timer/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/harvest_timer/harvest_timer/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/green.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/green.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/harvest_timer/harvest_timer/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/pqpath.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/pqpath.o
    psycopg/pqpath.c:135:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                    PQstatus(conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(*pgres)));
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    psycopg/pqpath.c:1714:11: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
        ret = 1;
              ^
    psycopg/pqpath.c:1819:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                    PQstatus(curs->conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(curs->pgres)));
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    3 warnings generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/harvest_timer/harvest_timer/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/utils.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/utils.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/harvest_timer/harvest_timer/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/bytes_format.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o
    In file included from psycopg/bytes_format.c:81:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^

    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/harvest_timer/harvest_timer/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/connection_int.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/connection_int.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/harvest_timer/harvest_timer/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/connection_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/connection_type.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/harvest_timer/harvest_timer/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/cursor_int.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/cursor_int.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/harvest_timer/harvest_timer/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/cursor_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/cursor_type.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/harvest_timer/harvest_timer/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/column_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/column_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/column_type.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
〜中略〜

    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/harvest_timer/harvest_timer/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/xid_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/xid_type.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/harvest_timer/harvest_timer/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_asis.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/harvest_timer/harvest_timer/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_binary.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/harvest_timer/harvest_timer/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_datetime.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/harvest_timer/harvest_timer/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_list.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/harvest_timer/harvest_timer/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pboolean.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/harvest_timer/harvest_timer/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/harvest_timer/harvest_timer/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pint.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/harvest_timer/harvest_timer/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pfloat.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/harvest_timer/harvest_timer/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_qstring.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/harvest_timer/harvest_timer/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/microprotocols.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/harvest_timer/harvest_timer/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o
    In file included from psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/harvest_timer/harvest_timer/venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/typecast.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/typecast.o
    gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/green.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/pqpath.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/utils.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/libpq_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/win32_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/solaris_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/connection_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/cursor_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/column_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_message_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/error_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/conninfo_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/lobject_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/lobject_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/notify_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/xid_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/typecast.o -L/usr/local/lib -lpq -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so
    ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/harvest_timer/harvest_timer/venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-install-plxviv83/psycopg2/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-xd6k1r8g/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/apple/GoogleDrive/harvest_timer/harvest_timer/venv/include/site/python3.7/psycopg2" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-plxviv83/psycopg2/
```

Comment: libssl が見つけられていなさそうです。ターミナルで `openssl version` と `type openssl` を実行した結果を本文に追記していただけませんでしょうか？　質問文下の「編集」から追記ができます。

Comment: 参考:[error installing psycopg2, library not found for -lssl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39244687)

Comment: ご協力ありがとうございます。
$ openssl version
LibreSSL 2.6.5

$ type openssl
openssl is hashed (/usr/bin/openssl)

となります

Answer (score 0, accepted):

一番重要そうなのはこのエラーメッセージです。このメッセージはライブラリのインストール時に libssl が見つかっていないことを示しています。

```
ld: library not found for -lssl
```

[metropolis さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/61299/mac%E3%81%AE%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AB%E3%83%AB%E7%92%B0%E5%A2%83%E3%81%ABpsycopg2%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84/61300?noredirect=1#comment66660_61299)の通り、英語版 Stack Overflow に類似質問がありました：[error installing psycopg2, library not found for -lssl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26288042/5989200)。[ひとつの回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39244687/5989200)は、まず `xcode-select --install` で各種バイナリをインストールすることを勧めています。他の方法として Homebrew で OpenSSL をインストールし、ライブラリの PATH を LDFLAGS で教えるものもありました。pip のキャッシュが悪さをすることもあるようで、`--no-cache` オプションも付いています。

```sh
env LDFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" pip --no-cache install psycopg2
```

また psycopg2 の issue を見ると同様の問題を挙げているものがありました：[Fails to build 2.8.4](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/997)。この issue では `brew install openssl` でインストールされた OpenSSL のパスを `LDFLAGS` と `CPPFLAGS` で指定することで解決しています。

Comment: ご協力ありがとうございます。

[ brew install openssl ]そした後、[export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"]を行い、再度psycopg2をインストールしましたが、エラーが続きます。エラーの内容は少し変わりました。後半の部分です。

Comment: Command "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/harvest_timer/venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-install-ncxoruy2/psycopg2/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-z3f6lzq2/install-record.txt

Comment: --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/apple/GoogleDrive/harvest_timer/venv/include/site/python3.7/psycopg2" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-ncxoruy2/psycopg2/

Comment: OpenSSlのパスを変更するのは、brew install opensslの後に、$ export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"、$ export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
とターミナルで行う方法で正しいでしょうか？

Comment: ご協力ありがとうございます。
pip --no-cache install psycopg2のコマンドで試してみましたが、インストールできず、エラーメッセージもかわりませんでした。

Comment: 上のメッセージは「このコマンドを実行したときにエラーが出たよ」と言っているだけで、どんなエラーが出たのかの情報が抜け落ちています。質問本文に追記するなどしてエラーメッセージをなるべく正確に載せてみてください。

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26288042/5989200、の解説の中の
env LDFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" pip install psycopg2
のコマンドで、インストールできました。
ご協力いただいた皆様、ありがとうございました

Comment: 良かったです。最初のコメントで `ld: library not found for -lssl` エラーは無くなったのかと思いましたが、エラーメッセージの追記を見てそうではないと分かりました。追記ありがとうございました。